# I want to collect state data from multiple components every time the state changes in each component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, jsx

So I am tasked to build an application where each component(5 components) has 1 editable table(components have no hierarchy). I am required to record the edits made in each component and make an AJAX call to a backend. The data that I send is going to be the edits from all the 5 components. What is the best way to approach a situation like this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright what I did end up doing is to store things in localStorage and retrieve them when appropriate.

Comment: This works for non sensitive data if the data is small.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all comes down to where you put the sate, if you put on top of the hierarchy you will be able to spread to all children when the state changes